# Laravel Redirecting to other file storage using Redirect::to()

Tags: laravel, redirect

```
$url = 'file:\\company8\Production\2018\2018-12\Product1';
return Redirect::to($url);
```

// this redirects to http://127.0.0.1:8000/file:/company8\Production\2018\2018-12\Product1

// How to make laravel redirect to 
file:/company8\Production\2018\2018-12\Product1

Answer (score 0):

You could use `return Redirect::away($url)`

Comment: same problem. i want redirect to file:/company8\Production\2018\2018-12\Product1. but it give me redirect to http://127.0.0.1:8000/file:/company8\Production\2018\2018-12\Product1

Comment: if you couldn't find an answer using laravel you might have to use header("Location: blabla")

Comment: by the way its file:// not file:/ so try again please

Comment: well then you most likely have to use header("Location: blabla")

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the backslash() to slash(/).

However You're unable to redirect to a file protocol due to security reason.

When you redirect to it

```
return Redirect::to("file://company8/Production/2018/2018-12/Product1");
```

you will receive `ERR_UNSAFE_REDIRECT` from chrome.

Try responding it through

```
return response()->file('/company8/Production/2018/2018-12/Product1');
```

Comment: i try it, but cannot work. return response()->file($url) only for open file. but the Product1 is folder.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Like I said there's no way to redirect to file protocol

Comment: Got way to Refresh response()->file? because pdf file content was updated, but it still show old file in cache. Is any way to refresh before open file?

Comment: Where did you implement the cache logic? In my case the file isn't cached.